# log4j2 RollingRandomAccessFile add one day in file name

Tags: java, log4j2

I have this in my log4j2.xml file:

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="${log-path}/server.log" 
        filePattern="${log-path}/server-%d{dd-MMM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss}.log"
        immediateFlush="false" append="true">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>[%p] %d %c [%t] [%marker] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="86400" modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>
```

I want that my log files are generated when the log file is more than 10mb and / or change the date.

I want this example:

**server.log** (today file) 
**server-27-10-2015-16-26-45.log** (today file) 
**server-27-10-2015-16-55-33.log** (today file) 
**server-28-10-2015-08-11-42.log** (tomorrow file)

But in my case, the first log file generated after server.log has the tomorrow date:

**server.log** (today file) 
**server-28-10-2015-16-26-45.log** (today file) 
**server-28-10-2015-16-55-33.log** (today file) 
**server-29-10-2015-08-11-42.log** (tomorrow file)

The files are created each 10 mb but I see that the date is not correct.
For some reason it adds 1 day to the file name.
Today is oct 27 and the first file created after overcoming 10 mb contains the tomorrow date (oct 28) in the name.

[image: Example that my logs files has been created]

Comment: how do you ensure that <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="86400" modulate="true" /> and <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" /> are mutually exclusive?

Comment: @AbtPst I don't know what is the difference if the modulate = "true" or "false". I changed that in my log4j2.xml but the problem keeps unsolved. Thanks.